# Spring @Transactional annonation not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I am facing an issue when I use a @Transactional annotation in a class which is extended by Service class. I know that Spring does Transaction Management only when a method is invoked by a Proxy but my problem is because of this annotation I am not able to get another Service class's property's value when accessing by object directly (property is public), but same I am able to fetch through getter method.

**Controller**

```java
package com.springbootdemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @Autowired
    Service1 service1;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public void index() {
        service1.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**Service1**

```java
package com.springbootdemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Service1 {
    @Autowired
    Service2 service2;

    public void doSomething(){
        service2.setSname("Hello");
        System.out.println("sname==> "+service2.sname);
        System.out.println("getSname==>"+service2.getSname());
    }
}
```

**UtilBean**

```java
package com.springbootdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
public class UtilBean {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String appendString(String s1) {
        return " Hi "+ s1;
    }
}
```

**Service2**

```java
package com.springbootdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Service2 extends UtilBean{
    public String sname;

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
#management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=loggers
#security.user.name=admin
#security.user.password=admin
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/aswaraj?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.session.store-type=none
security.basic.enabled=false
```

**Output**

```
sname==> null
getSname==>Hello
```

Comment: show your service-context.xml file ,where you have created hibernate connections.

Comment: This is a Spring boot application. I will post the application.properties as well as pom.xml

Comment: *****application.properties******

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

#management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=loggers

#security.user.name=admin

#security.user.password=admin

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/aswaraj?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username=root

spring.datasource.password=test

spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.session.store-type=none

security.basic.enabled=false

Comment: please post this in question.

Comment: If you already have a simple test project share it on github plz.
Anyway try to add the costructor to your service class

Comment: Just don't use public fields. They're well-known bad practices, for good reasons. Your example is one of them.

Comment: btw @JBNizet is totally right

Comment: @JBNizet I know it's a bad practice but I just wanted to why I am not able to the public field's value through Object. If it's a private field I can't access it through object, that's I referred this example.

Comment: @gaber84 will it not created a default constructor implicitly if I have not created any.

Comment: Because what is autowired is not your object. It's a proxy. But proxies can't proxy/override fields. Only methods.

Comment: Then if I remove @Transactional annotation from the class which is extended, after that "service2.sname" gives me the value. Why is it so?

Comment: Because since it's not transactional, Spring doesn't need to create a proxy around it.

Comment: You probably can not access this value because the proxy object is Lazy and it is populated only on the invocation of the getter.

About your question, it will use the default empty constructor and will inject using setter method, just try to use injection by with the constructor and you maybe trick the proxy.

Comment: @gaber84 I tried Constructor Injection too, but it didn't work.

Comment: @gaber84 Before accessing the field directly through proxy, I unwrapped it and converted to an Object and then I am able to get the value. But that's not the way I would like to do. Please suggest me some other way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please click "edit" to see how I just edited your question for you. I split your single big code block into several, added syntax highlighting, got rid of the empty lines between each pair of lines of code, took care of correct indentation. Next time please do that by yourself. Give your question some love, then your chances to get good answers are also higher. Good luck! :-)

Comment: I don't see any place in the code you shared where the annotated `appendString()` method is invoked.  So... when/where is it called?